# How to apply DATEVALUE to column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have extracted date values in `AM2:AO`:

|  | AM | AN | AO | AP | AQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **date** | **time** | **year** | **date value** | **time value** |
| **2** | Oct 12 | 14:15:00 | 2020 | 44116 | 0.59375 |

I am trying to create an array formula in AP2.  For each row in `AM2:AO`, CONCATENATE (or JOIN) the values in columns `AM` and `AO` and then pass that result into a DATEVALUE function.

Current formula in `AP2` that works for a single formula is:

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(AM2,", ",AO2))
```

I cannot apply this formula to the entire range using ARRAYFORMULA.

I've tried using CONCAT, JOIN, &, all without success.

Example of a formula that doesn't work:

```
=ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM & AO2:AO))
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What are the data types of column AM and AO values? Are the values of column AM text or date?

Comment: @Rubén I believe these are plain text.

Comment: Please be review that. What is shown in the formula bar when you select AM2? Have you tried to use ISTEXT, ISDATE functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula((V2:V5&"-"&MONTH(T2:T5)&"-"&DAY(T2:T5))*1)
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

If you want to apply for the whole range you can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(V2:V="",,(V2:V&"-"&MONTH(T2:T)&"-"&DAY(T2:T)*1)))
```

---

**EDIT**

Following OP's [request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146834/how-to-apply-datevalue-to-column#comment134422_146837)

> I actually wanted to keep this in the Datevalue format, e.g. 44116 instead of 10/12/2020.

Please use the following arrayformula

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(V2:V="",,((V2:V&"-"&MONTH(T2:T)&"-"&DAY(T2:T))*1)))
```

**DO notice the extra parenthesis**. They make all the difference.
Using this second formula you get the results as datevalues. If you then want to have them as dates, you can format them from the `Format -->Number -->Date` menu according to your preferences.

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`MONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052)
- [`DAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040)

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM&" "&AO2:AO)))
```

[image]

## Explanation

The formula is based on the assumption that Column `AM` is either formatted as "Plain text" or the values themselves are explicitly text strings such as `="Oct 12"` or `'Oct 12`).  This assumption is based on the fact that your single-row formula `=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(AM2,", ",AO2))` succeeded.   The formatting of column `AO` doesn't matter.

##### YOUR ATTEMPT

> `=ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM & AO2:AO))`

Your attempt using the [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) function was extremely close and your error was that **you did not include a delimiter** between the day and the year (you did have a delimiter in your single-row formula).

So, the following array formula would have worked:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM & " " & AO2:AO))`

[DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) is somewhat forgiving with respect to the actual delimiter used and a space, comma, combined comma and space, all work in my locale.  There are likely other options as well.

After that correction, all that remains is to optionally use [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) to deal with `#VALUE!` errors generated if a row in `AM2:AM` and/or `AO2:AO` doesn't contain a valid value.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM&" "&AO2:AO)))
```

alternatively

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(AM2:AM&" "&AO2:AO)))
```